# Inconsistent Error - Service using too much computer time for one day

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, quota

I have a script which performs an API call and pastes the result that has a time-based trigger set to run once per minute.
I've had it running for the last couple of days, and I'm pretty regularly getting notifications saying "Service using too much computer time for one day"

The thing I'm particularly perplexed about is that the error doesn't seem to be consistent. It's not failing every time the script runs.
For example, failures were logged at:

7:59 AM
8:15 AM
8:19 AM
8:24 AM

But the script ran every minute between those.

I looked into the execution logs and in total the script was running for approximately 4 hours over the course of yesterday (avg 10.3 sec/run).
Looking around, I have checked the [Google quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_quotas) and as far as I can tell, I am not hitting the limit (we are on the enterprise edition). The script also only has two triggers. One each minute, and one at midnight each day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Information about [Apps Script Exception messages](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations):

[image]

The triggers total runtime is 6hr/day, but this quota is per user, not per script. So if you have more than one script, the runtime adds up.

I recommend you to visit https://script.google.com/home/executions, see ALL executions without filters and sum the durations of all executions run on trigger (Type Trigger or time-driven).

If you upgraded to enterprise edition recently, keep in mind:

> Newly created G Suite domains are subject to the consumer limit for
>   the first billing cycle if they have six or more users, or several
>   billing cycles if they have fewer users.

Comment: Also, all of the quotas for Google Services are listed [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).